# For an operational amplifier, is the path from input to operational amplifier to output considered a feed forward path?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I actually don't have much knowledge about control systems or anything so based on what I have searched, people use both the terminologies feedforward path and forward path for the path which starts at the input, goes to the operational amplifier and ends at the output. This is to contrast it with the feedback path when a resistor is connected between the input and output terminals.

I just wonder if the term feedforward is appropriate because based on what I have read, the feedforward and feedback concepts are suppose to be like interventions to a certain process. The operational amplifier performs the process that we are talking about and it does go in the forward direction or input to output.

I am aware that feedforward is a term that is almost never used. I just want to get a better idea on what it is so I have something to compare with the concept of feedback.

Comment: Read up Black's work regarding feedforward. It's rarely used and has nothing to do with the direction of signal flow. I *have* used it myself and it's interestingly different to feedback. Op-amps rely on feedback to work so it's not relevant to them.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feed_forward_(control)

Comment: The forward path starts at the output of the comparator, and extends to the op amp output. The feedback path starts at the op amp output and extends to the comparator input. 'Feedforward' is something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of feedforward is so oblique to modern thinking that it rarely surfaces.

To compare, feedback uses the output, however non-linear the transfer characteristic of the 'forward path' may be, to modify the signal to correct the output's 'response' to approach linearity.

[Feedforward](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feed_forward_(control)) corrects the signal to the forward path in the inverse of it's non-linearity, thus achieving the same goal.

Combining both methods is the 'holy grail' of linear circuit designers.

Comment: So feedforward path and forward path aren't the same?

Comment: Feedforward is incorporated in the forward path. There is no feedback in this arrangement. The path includes some method of 'error correction'. With feedback, the error signal is derived by feedback action and added to the driving signal.

Comment: I'm confused by incorporated and not that it is the forward path. Like I would love it if that was the case so that you can say a feedback resistor and the feedforward path of the op amp are opposites. But that isn't exactly the case right?

Comment: The feedforward method 'modifies' the driving signal by the inverse of the system's natural non-linearity. It involves a model of the non-linearity. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feed_forward_(control)

Comment: Just re-reading your question, you seem to understand the principles well. Yes, the forward path is from input to output. The feedback path is from output to input. Operational amplifiers rely on (negative) feedback for their operation. Feedforward requires no feedback, relying on some inverse non-linearity of its transfer characteristic to 'cancel' the non-linearity of the 'load' acting in the reverse sense.

Comment: So the input to output path of the op amp isn't a feed forward I guess because it is suppose to be linear. I just got confused because a reference I read treated the term forward path and feedforward path as if they were synonymous and implied that the path is suppose to be treated as a polar opposite to the feedback in terms of terminologies and concepts.